# ¿Cómo buscar en una ruta, extraer el nombre de archivo, comparar y eliminar?

Tags: linux, bash, centos7

En un directorio /usr/local/prueba tengo archivos (a2.i, b3.i y d6.i) y (a2.pdf, b3.pdf) lo que desea hacer que, si existe el archivo con extensión `.i`, entonces se borre el que tiene el mismo nombre pero con extension `.pdf`

He intentado lo siguiente:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 FICHERO=$(find /usr/local/script/ -name "*.i")
 NOMBRE="${FICHERO%.*}"

 echo $NOMBRE
```

Pero el resultado es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me muestra la ruta y solo el ultimo documento muestra solo el nombre, los primeros se muestran con extensión `.i`

Comment: ¿Qué haz intentado? Para que se te ayude sobre tu duda.

Comment: #!/bin/bash
FICHERO=$(find /usr/local/script/ -name "*.i")
NOMBRE="${FICHERO%.*}"

echo $NOMBRE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Otra opción es usar perl, que viene virtualmente en cualquier distribución linux.

Para borrar todos los `.pdf` únicamente si existe un `.i` nombrado igual:

```
find /usr/local/script/ -name "*.i" | perl -ne 's/[.]i\n/.pdf/ && unlink'
```

Para borrar los `.i` y `.pdf` que tienen el mismo nombre (ignorando los que no tengan la extensión contraria)

```
find /usr/local/script/ -name "*.i" | perl -ne 's/[.]i\n// && -e "$_.i" && -e "$_.pdf" && unlink "$_.i", "$_.pdf"'
```

Comment: ¡Súper con `perl`!

Answer (score 5):

Se puede hacer sin la necesidad de un script con la opción que te voy a ofrecer.

```
find /usr/local/script/ -name "*.i" | sed -r 's/(.*).i$/\1\.pdf/g' | xargs -I {} bash -c "[[ -a {} ]] && ls -l {}"
#                                    |____________________________|          |            |______________________|
#                                                |                           |                      |______ Pregunta si existe el archivo (pero por el comando anterior 
#                                                |                           |                       será uno con extensión .pdf).
#                                                |                           |                       Si es así, entonces ejecuta el comando
#                                                |                           |                       de la derecha del token &&.
#                                                |                           |
#                                                |                           |___ xargs opera sobre cada linea del stdin, y con -I {}
#                                                |                                cada argumento se usara en la variable {}. Puedes
#                                                |                                usar otro.
#                                                |
#                                                |____ Todo lo que tenga extensión .i (osea, termine con .i), lo reemplazaré
#                                                      con la extensión .pdf
```

Sólo que para borrar, en lugar de, al final, poner un `ls -l {}` (sólo lo puse para que compruebes que funcione), puedes poner un `rm {}` si te sientes seguro. Ya después de poner `rm {}` borra los archivos con extensión `.pdf` que existan y que tengan el mismo nombre que los `.i` listados.

Comment: Uy genial lo validé y me funcionó, también probé moviendo los pdf y funciona!!!, pero tengo una duda como podría borrar los i y los pdf que tienen el mismo nombre y obviamente los i y los pdf que no tengan la extensión contraria no eliminarlos.

Comment: Que bien que te haya funcionado. Si te funcionó puedes calificar mi respuesta como válida. Referente a tu pregunta, puedes intentarlo por tu cuenta y, si tienes dudas, hacer otro post con esa nueva pregunta. Sin duda seré uno de los que traten de ayudarte.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, lo estuve intentando pero no logro borrar, ya hice el post, espero puedas ayudarme.

Comment: @Edgar Para borrar tienes que poner un `rm {}` en lugar de un `ls -l {}`. Justo como dije al final de mi post. Observa bien el comando y su explicación y al final se muestra que con `ls -l {}` se listan los ".pdf", entones, si pones `rm {}` se borran los ".pdf". Es decir, sólo sigue lo dicho hasta el final: cambia de `ls -l {}` a `rm {}`.

Comment: Amigo eso sí sé y como te he comentado también funciona moviendo a otro directorio, pero lo que quiero es que borre el pdf y el i con nombre iguales