# ¿Cómo buscar en una ruta, extraer el nombre de archivo, comparar y eliminar los dos archivos con mismo nombre pero con diferentes extensiones?

Tags: linux, bash, centos

En un directorio `/usr/local/prueba` tengo archivos (a2.i, b3.i y d6.i) y (a2.pdf, b3.pdf) lo que deseo hacer es, si existe el archivo con extensión .i, entonces se borre el que tiene el mismo nombre con extensión *.i y *.pdf

Con este comando:

```
find /usr/local/script/ -name "*.i" | sed -r 's/(.*).i$/\1\.pdf/g' | xargs -I {} bash -c "[[ -a {} ]] && ls -l {}"
```

Se busca, compara y se elimina el archivo .pdf, pero tengo una duda como podría borrar los i y los pdf que tienen el mismo nombre y obviamente los i y los pdf que no tengan la extensión contraria no eliminarlos

Comment: En tu pregunta anterior te puse un ejemplo para este caso ;-) https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/333582/c%c3%b3mo-buscar-en-una-ruta-extraer-el-nombre-de-archivo-comparar-y-eliminar . Si te sirve creo que se podría cerrar esta pregunta

Comment: @Edgar Con ese comando no se elimina el archivo `.pdf` sino que se lista si es que existe.

Answer (score 0):

Una variante del comando utilizado en tu anterior pregunta sería esta:

```
find /usr/local/prueba  -name "*.i" | grep -Po '.*(?=\.i$)' | xargs -I % bash -c '[[ -a "%".i && -a "%".pdf ]]  && echo Existen ambos de "%"'
#                                    |_____________________|                      |__________________________|      |____ Puedes poner "rm %.i %.pdf" en lugar del "echo... " 
#                                               |                                                |                             o rm "%"{.i,.pdf}                  
#                                               |                                                |
#                                               |                                                |___ Pregunto por el mismo nombre de 
#                                               |                                                     archivo pero con diferentes extensiones. 
#                                               |
#                                               |
#                                               |
#                                               |__ Utilizo una expresión regular para
#                                                   extraer únicamente el nombre completo
#                                                   quitando la extensión.
```

La expresión regular muestra únicamente lo que este antes de `.i`.

Comment: Esta pregunta es un casi igual a la anterior https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/333582/c%c3%b3mo-buscar-en-una-ruta-extraer-el-nombre-de-archivo-comparar-y-eliminar Si te parece podrías añadir esta respuesta como complemento a la respuesta anterior y podríamos solicitar cerrar la pregunta actual